# reverse array index position in array of array in JS

Tags: javascript

i Have a array

```
var arr = [["25","98"],["28","94"],["24","91"]]
```

how to make this array like in JS

```
var Newarr = [["98","25"],["94", "28"],["91", "24"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to reiterate the array. You can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...v]` each array to make a new array (and won't affect the original array). Use `reverse` to reverse it.

```js
var arr = [["25","98"],["28","94"],["24","91"]];

var Newarr = arr.map( v=> [...v].reverse() );
 
console.log(Newarr);
```

Comment: Nice usage of the spread operator (ES 2017), but I think you should flank that with an explanation.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and `slice()` to create new array and copy each sub-array inside and then and `reverse()` method.

```js
var arr = [["25","98"],["28","94"],["24","91"]]
const reverse = arr.map(e => e.slice().reverse());
console.log(reverse)
```

You could also do this with `map()` and `reduceRight()` methods.

```js
var arr = [["25","98"],["28","94"],["24","91"]]
const reverse = arr.map(e => e.reduceRight((r, e) => r.concat(e), []));
console.log(reverse)
```

Comment: Why `.slice()`?

Comment: Otherwise you are changing original array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map` and a sequence of `Array.prototype.slice` then`Array.prototype.reverse`:

```js
let arr = [["25","98"],["28","94"],["24","91"]]

console.log(
  arr.map(
    x => x.slice().reverse()
  )
)

console.log(arr)
```

If you omit the  `slice()` then the `.reverse()` changes the original `arr`.